# Media Queries: Targeting orientation: landscape without excluding desktop computers

Tags: iphone, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am building a responsive page at the moment but I have a problem.
For larger screen sizes I want to enlarge stuff like headings. This works, but testing the page on my iPhone in landscape mode, the headings are too big.

Why the iPhone in portrait triggers a media query for larger screens? Well, the CSS rule that enlarges the headings is enclosed in this media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
    /* 480 pixel */
}
```

and the iPhone screen in landscape is 480px wide. So I tried to do it like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) not (orientation: landscape) {
        /* 480 pixel* /
}
```

Now it works on my iPhone, but the headings aren't enlarged anymore on my MacBook. Probably it's just some kind of logical error, but where am I going wrong?

Comment: `only screen and (min-width: 30em) not (orientation: landscape)` is not a valid media query according to the spec. Odd that it works on the iPhone, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `not (orientation:landscape)` with `and (orientation:portrait)`. That failing, try changing the `em` values to `px` values. Some browsers don't play nice with `em` yet, so it's worth a shot.

EDIT: Why not just break it up into separate styles?

```
@media all and (min-width:480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    // styles for desktops, mouse-friendly interface
}

@media all and (min-width:480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    // styles for mobiles, touch-friendly interface
}
```

Comment: Did not help, sorry. The landscape media query is still triggered on my MacBook. I believe this is happening because the screen is "widescreen", meaning its wider than tall.

Comment: Yes, that would be the reason it's triggering. I'll update the answer in a minute with another possible solution.

Comment: `@media all and (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
/*stuff*/ }` did the trick. I'll accept your answer because you lead me to it!

Comment: Much obliged. Happy coding!